# How do I reverse attrib settings to default?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-attributes, help-files

How do I reverse attrib settings to default? I put the command "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:*.*" (X = Drive letter) and now it shows hidden files and folders. I then put the command "ATTRIB +H +R +S /S /D X:*.*" and it says that the drive is empty but the side bar still shows folders. When I go to these folders, they are also empty. How do I revert the attributes back to default?

Answer (score 0):

You either must reverse your actions, or else remove additional properties and set up any needed ones. The main needed one is "a" Archive.

https://winaero.com/blog/modify-or-remove-file-property-details-in-windows-10/

A very brief description follows.

> How to Remove File Property Details
>
> Open File Explorer. Go to the folder where you store the file you want
> to remove extra file property details from. Right-click the file and
> select "Properties" from the context menu.

Display Attributes with xPlorer2 (I use this) or Windows File Explorer.  In File Explorer, View Tab, Add Columns, Choose Columns to Add and scroll down, select Attribute.

[image]

Comment: What should I specifically do to reverse the action? I put in "attrib +H +R +S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" (asterisk doesn't show up when typed here) and it just removed the files from the flash drive from access through the windows explorer (no files showed up; folders still appear in sidebar). What do I specifically type to reverse my action (ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk])?

Comment: You can only reverse what you did. That is, use attrib to change what you had initially done. If you cannot recall the exact settings you made, then you must clear all attributes and, if needed, set up new attributes.

Comment: I told you exactly what I did. (1) I put in "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" and it showed the hidden files. (2) I put the opposite "ATTRIB +H +R +S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" and all the files were gone. (3) I put "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" again and went back to the same stage as (1). What do I specifically type to reverse "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]"? I'm thinking of just doing "ATTRIB +H /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]"? Will this revert it back to default?

Comment: Try the last thing you suggested.  There is not a real "default" except normally "a" (archive) attribute. That is why I suggest clearing all attributes except "a"

Comment: Should I type "ATTRIB +H /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" or do what you're suggesting? If the latter, then what should I specifically type to clear all attributes except "a"?

Comment: Look at the attributes on your files. Do not remove "a" - that was all.

Comment: If you mean the attributes that are in the properties window, I can't remove anything and can only check "read-only" and "hidden". If you mean in command prompt, I should type "ATTRIB +A /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]"? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Try that and see.  I have used attributes but not messed them up in this way.

Comment: Use xPlorer2 or Windows File Explorer to show the attributes. This will make it much easier to see what you have to change. You can see what I meant about Default for most files being "A"

Comment: Did all your files reappear or all they all hidden? If you didn't  save a list of the files that initially had the **R|H|S** attributes set before issuing your blanket clear command, there is no way to know which files need those attributes reset. I'm not sure if File History records a change of attributes -- assuming it was enabled for the drive in the first place. Without some sort of backup, you have to determine which files had one or more of those attributes.

Comment: The only consistent, common occurrences of those I can think of is **H+S** for **desktop.ini** files, along with **R** set for their parent folders. **H+S** for **folder.jpg** and **AlbumArtSmall.jpg** files. Hard to say any more w/o knowing the nature of the content of the drive.

Comment: Keith, folders and files that are supposed to be hidden are now shown (e.g. "._.Trashes"). I'm looking for a way to put it back to its factory default; when I first used the flash drive.

Comment: John, do you mean I should type "ATTRIB +A /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]"? Could you please tell me what I should expect happen when I do it?

Comment: Typing ATTRIB  +A should not hurt as A is (more or less) default.  I am not sure what will happen if you try this on a collection of files at one go. Make a backup of the files and then try it.

Comment: Yes, I have a backup on the computer's drive. If things do go wrong, what should I do next?

Comment: Try the command you listed.

Comment: Which command? "ATTRIB +H /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" or "ATTRIB +A /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]"?

Comment: Try the second one so the the A attribute is left intact.

Comment: If it goes wrong, should I use "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:[asterisk].[asterisk]" again to revert it to this stage?

Comment: That is something you can try

Comment: Can you tell me a method that you are absolutely certain of? I don't want to complicate problems more.

Comment: I have not messed up attributes, so I can only confirm what you are trying.

Comment: Maybe you can point me to a forum or person that has experience with these issues?

Comment: I have not seen such a forum, so I cannot help with that. Sorry.

Comment: Try this article (not much different than my answer earlier)  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-reset-all-original-attribute-of-files-in/79a713fc-5000-4a70-adae-bc056d2d5417

Comment: This article is for Windows 7 and additionally I only changed the attributes for the flash drive.

Comment: Attributes work the same way for most recent systems and drives

Comment: What do you mean attributes work the same way? What way? And what recent systems or drives?

Comment: There is no mass default or settings. You need to look at the files (I showed how up top) and unset properties you do not need and set the A attribute.